# How to make a foreign key within a model

Tags: mysql, prisma

After reading the prisma documentation, I came across the @relation func to create a relation to another model. My goal is to make organization_id in my project table a foreign key in relation to my organization table. However upon generating the database i receive the error:

```
      Error validating field `organization_id` in model `project`: The relation field `organization` on Model `project` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `organization`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually.
          -->  schema.prisma:34
           |
        33 |   created DateTime
        34 |   organization_id organization @relation(fields: id, references: org_id)
        35 |   content_title String
```

Here is the schema:

```
model organization {
  org_id String @id
  created DateTime
  Name String?
  credit_balance Decimal @db.Decimal(9,2)
}

    model project {
      id String @id
      created DateTime
      organization_id organization @relation(fields: id, references: org_id)
      content_title String 
      content_id String?
      client_key String
      has_data Boolean
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message said, just simply format your schema, prisma will automatically fix the problem for you (Pressing `Alt + Shift + F` in VS code for example).

Or you can do it manually by adding `project project[]` to `model organization`

```prisma
model organization {
  org_id         String    @id
  created        DateTime
  Name           String?
  credit_balance Decimal   @db.Decimal(9, 2)
  project        project[] // Adding manually or using code formatter
}

model project {
  id              String       @id
  created         DateTime
  organization_id organization @relation(fields: id, references: org_id)
  content_title   String
  content_id      String?
  client_key      String
  has_data        Boolean
}
```

Comment: So it was just a formatting error? Thought my logic was wrong thanks!

Comment: @macman926 No, it's a logic error. But prisma can fix this error for you.